# Web Start is working but jenkins says "Ping response time is too long or timed out"

Tags: windows, jenkins, jenkins-agent

I can successfully start the connection from the slave with this command:

```
java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl https://myserver:8888/computer/myslave/slave-agent.jnlp -secret sdfsdfsdf -workDir "c:\jenkins"
```

It start, it runs, it logs 0 errors, I do netstat on the master and see the connection is established.

But it says its offline with the error "Ping response time is too long or timed out"

The error itself is troubling because the whole point of web start is so the master doesn't need direct access to the slave. Is it actually trying to icmp to the slave?

The slave can only access the master over port 8888.

I also see no logs anywhere for this, not on the slave or the master, how do I know what jenkins is even trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to allow this slave connection through a firewall.

I thought I could get away with one port for this.

My thinking was, opening up jenkins on port 8888 and listen to jnlp on port 8888 then connect with command `java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl https://myserver:8888/computer/myslave/slave-agent.jnlp ....`

But I needed open up port 433 so i could connect to the server over https first and connect like `java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl https://myserver/computer/myslave/slave-agent.jnlp ....`. Then also open port 8888 so the jenkins server could redirect to that jnlp port.

I was making a jnlp connection directly to that open port, the problem was I needed to connect to the jenkins server and let the server setup that jnlp connection